# Python def / function issue

Tags: python

I wanted to make a menu for a restaurant. Because I am new, I wanted to make not a-lot of choices so I got a random excuse but thats not my problem right now.
I just need help as when I do my `def _menu_():` code, for some reason it doesn't work in the shell it just does something like `<function _menu_ at 0x7fa592bf0430>` and I don’t really know how to fix it...

```
import sys
menu_choice = ('ok i will stay')

def _menu_():
    print('|---------------------------|')
    print('|Kids menu:                 |')
    print('| Chicken nuggets(G)        |')
    print('| Medium size MAC(G)        |')
    print('| EXTRA Fries (GF)          |')
    print('|*all menu comes with fries*|')
    print('|G = GLUTEN GF = GLUTENFREE |')
    print('|---------------------------|')

    
print('Owner:')
print ('hello, i am the owner of the restaurant, unfortunately we have been robbed and all our food is gone except for our catch of the day and our kids menu')
print('    ')
print('is it ok or you want to go to another restaurant (knowing that our prices reduced by 75%)')
print('write "ok i will stay" if you want to eat here and write "nevermind i will go see somewhere else" to go somewhere else')

menu_choice = ('ok i will stay')

if menu_choice:
    print('ok great so what will you take here is the menu')
    print (_menu_)
else:
    print('ok then, enjoy you expensive other restaurant')
    sys.exit
```

(btw, it is not finished yet I can do a-lot more)

Comment: `print (_menu_())` and `sys.exit()`. Functions/methods should be called. Read: [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: You're printing the function, you should call it. Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues, Ill try to address them.

---

```
print (_menu_)
```

Prints the `_menu_` function, you want to call it like so:

```
_menu_()
```

No need to use `print()` since `_menu_` uses `print` itself.

---

```
sys.exit
```

Should be called like a function too:

```
sys.exit()
```

---

```
menu_choice = ('ok i will stay')
if menu_choice:
```

The `if` probably does not way you want. You should define `menu_choice` as a string, and compare it:

```
menu_choice = 'Ok i will stay'

if menu_choice == 'Ok i wil stay'
```

There's no need to define it twice.

---

Eventually, the code would become something like

```py
import sys

def _menu_():
    print('|---------------------------|')
    print('|Kids menu:                 |')
    print('| Chicken nuggets(G)        |')
    print('| Medium size MAC(G)        |')
    print('| EXTRA Fries (GF)          |')
    print('|*all menu comes with fries*|')
    print('|G = GLUTEN GF = GLUTENFREE |')
    print('|---------------------------|')

    
print('Owner:')
print ('hello, i am the owner of the restaurant, unfortunately we have been robbed and all our food is gone except for our catch of the day and our kids menu')
print('    ')
print('is it ok or you want to go to another restaurant (knowing that our prices reduced by 75%)')
print('write "ok i will stay" if you want to eat here and write "nevermind i will go see somewhere else" to go somewhere else')

menu_choice = 'ok i will stay'

if menu_choice == 'ok i will stay':
    print('ok great so what will you take here is the menu')
    _menu_()
else:
    print('ok then, enjoy you expensive other restaurant')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: thx again... so now i could still add another ```def``` the 'catch of the day' thing? (i can do that myself after the examples you've given me)

Comment: 1 last thing, if i want to answer and not have the ```_menu_``` directly, what do i do? like when i run the code, it straight away prints the ```_menu_```and i want to answer the 
```print('write "ok i will stay" if you want to eat here and write "nevermind i will go see somewhere else" to go somewhere else')
```
and the
 
```if menu_choice == 'ok i will stay':
    print('ok great so what will you take here is the menu')
    _menu_()
else:
    print('ok then, enjoy you expensive other restaurant')
    sys.exit() ```

Comment: You mean that you have to type 'ok i will stay'? Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_user_input.asp